# Android: how to Play Mp3 sound as a notification?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have a countdown that, when it is done, it invokes the following `onFinish` method:

```
public void onFinish() {
    azanCountdownH1.setText("Get ready now");
}
```

In order to be able to play a mp3 file at the end of the countdown, I changed the `onFinish` method to:

```
public void onFinish() {
    playNotification();
    azanCountdownH1.setText("Get ready now");
}
```

Where `playNotification` looks exactly like:

```
public static void playNotification(){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyApplicationContext.getAppContext(), R.raw.azan);
    mp.start();
}
```

But it is not working !!

On Android Moniter on `Android-Studio` it is showing the following:

[image]

Any suugestion on what or where the bug might be ?!

Comment: `MyApplicationContext.getAppContext()` should be `YourActivity.this`. You're not passing proper context.

Comment: @ReazMurshed You were right .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Context` you pass to MediaPlayer.create() is **null**. I would suggest to pass the `Context` to your playNotification method:

```
public void onFinish() {
    playNotification(this);
    azanCountdownH1.setText("Get ready now");
}


public static void playNotification(Context context){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.azan);
    mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to this code hope this can help you..

```
public void onFinish() {
    azanCountdownH1.setText("Get ready now");
    playNotification(youractivity.this);
}

public void playNotification(Context context){
  MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
  mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.azan);
  mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be passing a wrong `Context` so just replace `Activity.this` with your `Activity` name

```
public static void playNotification(){
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(Activity.this, R.raw.azan);        
    if(mediaplayer == null) {            
        Log.v(TAG, "Create() on MediaPlayer failed.");       
    } else {
    mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
            mediaplayer.stop();
            mediaplayer.release();
        }
    });

    mediaplayer.start();
    }
}
```